# Android socket implementation with AsyncTask force close

Tags: java, android, sockets, android-asynctask

I'm facing with an issue when try to send 'signal' to my `AsyncTask` class to stop execution and close socket connection. In `doInBackground` method I setting up socket connection, sending first payload packet and waiting for incoming packets:

```
mRunning = true;

        try {
            byte[] data = null;

            mSocket = mTlsSocketFactory.createSocket(mTlsSocketFactory.getServerAddress(), mTlsSocketFactory.getServerPort());
            LogHelper.printLogMsg("INFO socket created");

            out = new DataOutputStream(mSocket.getOutputStream());
            out.flush();
            inStream = new DataInputStream(mSocket.getInputStream());

            //send authenticate payload
            requestSendPayload(authenticatePayload, params);

            while (mRunning) {
                int type = inStream.readInt();
                type = Integer.reverseBytes(type);
                mResID = type;
                int length = inStream.readInt();
                length = Integer.reverseBytes(length);
                if (length > 0) {
                    data = new byte[length];
                    inStream.readFully(data);
                    publishProgress(data);
                }
                data = null;
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (out != null) out.close();
                if (inStream != null) inStream.close();
                if (mSocket != null) mSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.fillInStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

When I receive packet that I want, I should close connection. I have a public method inside `AsyncTask` class:

```
public void close() {
   mRunning = false;
}
```

But the problem is that 'while' block never ends and `doInBackground` never finished.
There is a lot of posts with similar problem but I tried to call cancel(true) on my `AsyncTask` but with no result - `doInBackground` never finished. My question is how to send 'signal' to `doInBackground` method so that my while loop be able to finish?

I can rewrite closeMethod to something like this:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    if (out != null) out.close();
                    if (inStream != null) inStream.close();
                    if (mSocket != null) mSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.fillInStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
```

And after that, I catch exception when try to read: `DataInputStream.readInt()` and then `doInBackground` will end. But I'm not sure if this is the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement OnCancelled in your async task method

```
@Override
protected void onCancelled() {
   mRunning = false;
}
```

after that you just call

```
mySocketAsyncTaskObject.cancel(false);
```

Another option would be to remove your mRunning property and OnCancelled override and just check for IsCancelled()

```
while (!IsCancelled()) {
                int type = inStream.readInt();
                type = Integer.reverseBytes(type);
                mResID = type;
                int length = inStream.readInt();
                length = Integer.reverseBytes(length);
                if (length > 0) {
                    data = new byte[length];
                    inStream.readFully(data);
                    publishProgress(data);
                }
                data = null;
            }
```

As a personal note, i want to add, that it is good practice to use Service class for incapsulation your Socket functionality and use plain Thread object not AsyncTask

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the first solution not working because onCancelled never gets called. From the docs: "Calling the cancel() method will result in onCancelled(Object) being invoked on the UI thread after doInBackground(Object[]) returns". My doInBackground never ends so onCancelled is not called. I tried with second solution but it seems that is not working either - I'm calling: myAsyncTaskObj.cancel(true); but doInBackground never finished. And yes, I read that the AsyncTask class is not such a good solution and maybe I'm thinking to re-implement this.

Comment: try passing false to cancel method, that way, thread would not be interrupted, and IsCancelled() should return true

Comment: No, unfortunately nothing happens.